# Differential equation/ uniqueness of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find out, wether the solution of 
$$x'(t)=x \ln x, x(0)=x_0>0 $$ is unique.
The solution is $$x=x_0e^{e^{t}}$$ 
It holds for all $t \in \mathbb R$.

Thus, $f:=x \ln x$ is continuous and Lipschitz  $\forall x>0$. So I would say the solution is unique. Am I right?

Comment: The solution is $x=x_0^{e^t}$, not $x_0e^{e^t}$ !

Comment: Ok, but the solution is unique too?

Comment: Your function $f$ isn't lipschitz on R⁺*, since its derivative isn't bounded. But $f$ is C¹ which is sufficient to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: But if f is $C^1$, then it's locally lipschiitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that equation directly by separation of variables to check that the solution is unique:
\begin{align}
\int_{x_0}^x \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y\ln y} & = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1/y}{\ln y}\,\mathrm{d}y \\
& = \ln \lvert \ln y\rvert \Big|_{x_0}^x = \int_0^{t} \mathrm{d}s =t.
\end{align}
By the properties of logarithms $\ln\lvert \ln y \rvert \Big|_{x_0}^x = \ln \Big\lvert \frac{\ln x}{\ln x_0}\Big\rvert$, so
$$
\ln \Big\lvert \frac{\ln x}{\ln x_0}\Big \rvert = t \Rightarrow \lvert \ln  x \rvert = \lvert \ln x_0\rvert e^t \Rightarrow x(t) = e^{\pm \lvert \ln x_0 \rvert e^t}. 
$$

Comment: Can't you leave $|ln x_0|$ out, because  x_0>0?

Comment: So that means, the solution is unique?

Comment: What do you mean? Yes, I found the solution by computing it, it is unique.

Comment: Because of x0>0 can't you simply write $x=x_0^{e^{t}}$

Comment: If I understand correctly what you say, be careful: $x_0 > 0$ does not imply $\ln x_0 > 0$. When $0 < x_0 < 1$ you have $\ln x_0 < 0$. Anyway yes, you can simplify further the expression I got.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

The function

$$x(z):=e^{e^z}$$ is invertible and infinitely differentiable. It turns the equation to

$$e^ze^{e^z}\frac{dz}{dt}=e^ze^{e^z}$$ or $$\frac{dz}{dt}=1,$$ that has the solutions $$z=t+C$$ and only these.